# Debugging in QT Creator "This does not seem to be a Debug build."

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault, qt-creator

I am trying to debug some racket code using QTCreator 2.2.81 and keep getting the message "This does not seem to be a "Debug" build". As a result, I wanted to make sure that I could at least debug the program in gdb. I found that I could not do it in GDB witout adding the following lines to my .gdbinit file:

```
handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint
handle SIG33 nostop noprint pass
handle SIG32 nostop noprint pass
```

Once I did this, I was able to successfully debug the program using GDB. I don't mind using GDB, but it's not part of my normal work flow and I'd rather use the built-in features that Qt Creator offers. I made sure that the option was checked to use my.gdbinit file in Qt Creator and I still ran into the same problems. Any advice on what I need to do to get debugging in qt?

Comment: In my case, a full rebuild of the project after changing the project build setting to Debug solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following to your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += debug
```

Comment: This works in the short term, but prevents building a release build. Rather, this should be passed on the QMake command line: `qmake CONFIG+=debug`. In Qt Creator, this can be configured under Projects > Desktop > Build (and is normally listed there already).